# Input variable into $.post

Tags: jquery, variables, post, var

I try to use this jQuery code to call for Changes.php with $_POST["fname"] = Jones:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
                var $x = 'Jones';
        $.post("Changes.php", { fname: $X } );
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work!

What I am doing wrong? If I put $X in '' - fname becomes $X, not Jones.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the capitalized X a typo?

Comment: do not use tags unrelated to your question. PHP removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable names are case sensitive in JS, use a lowercase `x`:

```
$.post("Changes.php", { fname: $x} );
```

Comment: Additionally, they also do not require a dollar sign as prefix, "x" is a perfectly valid javascript variable name.

Comment: @Sven Yeah, but there isn't anything wrong with `$` prefixed variables. I ain't gonna fix it if it ain't broken.

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var x = 'Jones';
        $.post("Changes.php", { fname:x } );
    });
</script>
```

Problem with your script was you were creating var x with small 'x' and while assigning you were using capital X, also using $ at the start of file is not allowing in javascript

Comment: Oh I have changed that before your comment appear, thanx anyway